# Keep the selected documents between pager's pages in view

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I created XPages dialog box which shows users view in domino directory. The dialog box can pick up a user and save the user ID.
However in some causes I'd like to pick up some of peoples in the dialog. When I move to another page by pager, the selected check box are cleared.

I found the similar question but this is very old. Now is there good way?
[Select All checkbox lotus xpages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569292/select-all-checkbox-lotus-xpages)

I know this is feasible by repeat control but in the current case there are many data(about 10000 users) and want to use 'search'. I'd like to use view control if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [viewPanelHelper code snippet](http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1062) from Sven Hasselbach adds the option to keep selections when paging.

Comment: I haven't completed full test but it seems to work well. If you have any information about issues, please share me! Again, thanks for great information!!